# Cascading attribute of @Mocked in JMockIt

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jmockit

Hey i'm trying to upgrade my JMockIt from version 1.14 to version 1.18. A lot of mocked objects in the class i'm working on use cascading attribute of @Mocked

```
@Mocked(cascading = false)
```

It appears that the attribute was removed in version 1.17. After upgrading JMockIt I will probably have to delete this attribute and my question is how did the attribute used to affect the mocked objects? Will all the tests work in the same way after deleting the attribute? If not what changes I would have to make to my code?
I haven't used JMockIT for a long time and I'm unable to find any informations about this on the internet.I think the fact that it is no longer supported had something to do with that.
Thanks

Comment: Did you see the [release notes](http://jmockit.org/changes.html#1.17)?

Comment: @Rogerio I haven't used the JMockIt for a long time so I wasn't sure how the change will affect the rest of the code. In the release notes it only says that existing tests should omit the attribute or use partial mocking so I'm not sure where to use each solution. I also forgot to mention that some of the tests are not mine and are very complicated. Anyway so will omitting the attribute cause no changes to the code?

Comment: The replacement for `@Mocked(cascading = false)` is to "omit the attribute, or record an expectation with `result = null` for the cascaded method in question". There is no way to know which beforehand, since it depends on what the test needs.

Comment: @Rogerio Yes but in which test cases should I simply omit the attribute and in which should I record expectation with result= null?

Comment: As I said, it depends on what the test needs.

Comment: Having looked at the release notes for a similar issue, there sure seems to be a lot of removing going on about two to three months after deprecating an item. From my experience, that's quite a bit too quick for most dev teams, and it'll make upgrading between minor releases rather painful.